# Is Greasemonkey not capable of using jQuery's full power?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to find an element using jQuery, but it is not working.. I found out that this kind of selector can't be done in Greasemonkey:

```
($("#app7019261521_hover_container > [id^=app7019261521_the_coin]"))
```

Please help me translate this into raw Javascript. This kind of selector is hardcore to do in Javascript. Please help me Javascript gurus!

Comment: This works for me in GreaseMonkey.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, and now I remember why I started using jQuery:

```
var children = document.getElementById('app7019261521_hover_container').childNodes;
var ids = []; //to store the IDs of all matching elements
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
    //indexOf returns zero is subject starts with passed string
    if(children.item(i).id.indexOf('app7019261521_the_coin') == 0)
    {
        alert('Got One!');
        ids.push(children.item(i).id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are targeting directly to Firefox, you may want to give a look to the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) implemented on [Firefox 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors).

Check the [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) function:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#app7019261521_hover_container > [id^=app7019261521_the_coin]")
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if this works. If jQuery doesn't work then this shouldn't either, afterall, in capable browsers, jQuery (Sizzle) uses document.querySelectorAll...